# Doctrine 2 integration problems

Tags: php, zend-framework, integration, doctrine-orm

The issue:

I'm developing my project using MVC pattern.
In order to build model I decided to use Doctrine 2 RC2.

For implement View and Controller I want to use Zend Framework 1.11.

While I've developing model I tested it. And the model works fine. Using Doctrine2 console tool I've create all tables in database and quite simply playing with the model entities. And I moved to next step - Integration Doctrine into ZendFramework.

When I finished integration I found follow error message: "Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message '**Class** Entities\Tourist **is not a valid entity or mapped super class**.'"

I thought that it's my fault. Then I decided to find the same ready for use package [Here is it](https://github.com/marsbomber/zf1-doctrine2/tree/modular_setup). I supposed it should works from the box, but it didn't happen. Downloaded package showed me the same error message: "**Class** Application_Model_Article **is not a valid entity or mapped super class.**"

Now I'm thinking that the problem is in my environtment. But what I need to change in order to get it work? Can anyone help me?

My Environtment:
OS: Mac OS X 10.6.5
PHP: 5.3.3 (installed over Macports)
Apache: 2.2 (installed over Macports)

Please advise me what is wrong? Does ZendFramework could overlap some Doctrine functionality?

Comment: Of course this is obvious, but I decided to add: When I use doctrine2 and ZF1.11 separately - they both works fine, the problem raise only when I'm trying integrate them.

Comment: Issue was solved by reinstall php 5.3.3 and all dependent libraries.

Comment: Please move your comment above to an answer.  It's OK to answer your own questions.